# Get the IP address of printer

Tags: android

I want  connect to the printer via wifi.In order to connect,i should find the ip address and port number of the printer.How to find them?

can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How to set a manual IP address on your printer:

When the printer is connected to the network the first time, the router will assign an IP address to it. To get the IP address that the printer was assigned, print a configuration page from the printer. It will show you the IP address on that page somewhere.

Using an Internet browser, type the IP address of the printer into the address line of the browser and press enter. It should bring up a printer configuration window.