# Find printer IP address from a list of ip addresses of network devices

Tags: android, networking, printing, android-wifi, android-networking

**Objective**-I need to detect my Brother QL-720NW label printer on wifi, in order to print from my application.

I have gone through various similar questions on SO like [Get the IP address of printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355254/get-the-ip-address-of-printer) , [How to connect a network printer over Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301132/how-to-connect-a-network-printer-over-android) ,[How to get IP adress of other hosts in same wifi network in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264907/how-to-get-ip-adress-of-other-hosts-in-same-wifi-network-in-android) etc

But none of the above solve my problem completely.

> Using this
>   [How to get IP address of the device from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device)
>   I'm able to get list of all ip addresses on my wifi network .

**CODE:**

```
String myIpAdd= getIPAddress(true);
ArrayList<InetAddress>  inetAddresses=getConnectedDevices(myIpAdd);

public ArrayList<InetAddress> getConnectedDevices(String YourPhoneIPAddress) {
        ArrayList<InetAddress> ret = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();

        LoopCurrentIP = 0;

        String IPAddress = "";
        String[] myIPArray = YourPhoneIPAddress.split("\\.");
        InetAddress currentPingAddr;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
            try {

                // build the next IP address
                currentPingAddr = InetAddress.getByName(myIPArray[0] + "." +
                        myIPArray[1] + "." +
                        myIPArray[2] + "." +
                        Integer.toString(LoopCurrentIP));

                // 50ms Timeout for the "ping"
                if (currentPingAddr.isReachable(50)) {

                    ret.add(currentPingAddr);
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            LoopCurrentIP++;
        }
        return ret;
    }

     /**
     * Get IP address from first non-localhost interface
     * @param ipv4  true=return ipv4, false=return ipv6
     * @return  address or empty string
     */
    public static String getIPAddress(boolean useIPv4) {
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
                List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
                for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                    if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress().toUpperCase();
                        boolean isIPv4 = InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(sAddr); 
                        if (useIPv4) {
                            if (isIPv4) 
                                return sAddr;
                        } else {
                            if (!isIPv4) {
                                int delim = sAddr.indexOf('%'); // drop ip6 port suffix
                                return delim<0 ? sAddr : sAddr.substring(0, delim);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } // for now eat exceptions
        return "";
    }
```

**How can I detect which Ip address is of my printer from the list of Ip addresses??**

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set it up in the printer if you are wanting to maintain a static ip address.  There's a chance after turning it off and back on that it would be assigned a new IP if you are on DHCP.  Once it's static you could just code it in the app or put it in a setting. That way you never need to search through the ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Well Rachita, I would add (just before adding to the list) a code to connect via Socket and test on port 9100 looking for a printer.
[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301132/how-to-connect-a-network-printer-over-android). Hope that helps